# sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

The following code:

```
for project in $projectlist
do
    echo $project
    ssh user@server 'awk "/^\[EARTH]/{flag=1; next} /\[PROJECT]/{flag=0} flag" /filepath/'${project}'/file |
    sed "s/^/'${project}'\;/g" | sed "s/^/test\;/g" | sed "s/\\/\;/g" | sed "s/\;//9g"' >> "$filepath"/data1.csv;

    ssh user@server 'awk "/\[VALUES]/{flag=1; next} /,0/{flag=0} flag" /filepath/'${project}'/file |
    sed "s/^/'${project}'\;/g" | sed "s/^/test\;/g" | sed "s/\\/\;/g" | sed "s/\"//g"' >> "$filepath"/data2.csv;

done
```

Gives the following output for each iteration:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

I have tried several attempts at reformating etc. but always run into this issue. I have escaped the semicolons inside, and none of the $project variables have slashes inside them. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `sed "s/^/'${project}'\;/g"` --> `sed "s/^/${project};/g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed "s/\\/\;/g"` is wrong. You can see the problem when you do just a

```
sed "s/\\/\;/g" <<<x
```

You also get a *unterminated `s' command*.

The double quotes turn on `\`-escaping, which means that `\\` is taken as a single backslash. Hence, sed sees the command `s/\/\;/g`, which in turn means that it sees only two forward slashes instead of one.

I don't know what you want to achieve, but i.e. `sed "s/\\//\;/g"` would be syntactically correct.

Comment: Wow, that explains it! Well, I want to replace all backslashes in the text selection with semicolons. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @bullfighter : `tr \\ ';'`

Comment: So basically swap the sed "s/\\/\;/g" with tr \\ ';' ? Will give it a try

Comment: That did the trick, using tr \\\\ ';' to remove the single \ warning as well